# How to load chart data to an appended canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm trying to load some data into my pie chart like this using ChartJS:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    data = {
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [10, 20, 30],
          backgroundColor: [
            "rgba(35, 209, 96, 1)",
            "rgba(50, 115, 220, 1)",
            "rgba(255, 59, 96, 1)"
          ]
        }
      ],

      labels: ["Positive", "Neutral", "Negative"]
    };

    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "pie",
      data: data,
      options: {}
    });
  });
```

My chart canvas is appended when i click a button

```
const appendChart = () => {
  $(document).on("click", "#btnInsights", function() {
    $("#extentionBody")
      .empty()
      .append("<canvas id='myChart'></canvas>");
  });
};
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'getContext' of undefined
>       at HTMLDocument. (content.js:160)
>       at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
>       at c (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)

Comment: The problem seems to be because the first block of code is running before you have added the `myChart` canvas to the DOM. I'd suggest putting that logic in a function and calling it after `append()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<canvas id='myChart'></canvas>` needs to exist before this 
`$(document).ready(function() { });`
You're literally calling something that doesn't yet exist. Your canvas only exists after pressing the button meaning that the code written on the `(document).ready()` function will execute right after the DOM is ready, technically right after your button is created, so it wont wait for the user to click it.

What I would do is on the **click** event, after you add the canvas populate it.

```
 $(document).on("click", "#btnInsights", function() {
   $("#extentionBody")
     .empty()
     .append("<canvas id='myChart'></canvas>");

   if(!!document.getElementById('myChart')) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    data = {
       datasets: [
        {
          data: [10, 20, 30],
          backgroundColor: [
            "rgba(35, 209, 96, 1)",
            "rgba(50, 115, 220, 1)",
            "rgba(255, 59, 96, 1)"
          ]
        }
      ], 
      labels: ["Positive", "Neutral", "Negative"]
    };
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "pie",
      data: data,
      options: {}
    });
  }
});
```